# How to insert into a map of vectors. map<int, vector<int>> map; I want to insert values into the vector one by one

Tags: c++, stl

I want to insert values into this vector, **Not all at once but
one by one**. How will I do this?
Like for e.g.
I want to insert 1,{2}.
Now I want to insert 1,{3} into the map of vectors again. The final value in the map should contain 1,{2,3}.
How do I do this?
If I use the insert function, then 3 won't be inserted
or if I use map[1] = 3 then 2 would be overwritten.

```
map<int, vector<int>> map;
    map.insert({1,{2}});
    map[1] = {3,4};
    for(auto pr: map)
    {
      cout<<  pr.first<< " ";
      for(auto pr1 :pr.second)
        cout << pr1 << endl;
    }
```

This is going to output 3,4 values for the 1st key in the map. I want 2,3,4 to be present in the vector.

Comment: `=` assigns. If you want to insert of push back you need to use `insert` or `push_back`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would you insert elements to a vector when it is not in a map? Not like this:

```
std::vector<int> v{2};
v = {3,4};
```

Because this replaces the whole vector with a different vector that has elements `3` and `4`. But like this:

```
std::vector<int> v{2};
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);
```

It works the same when the vector is inside a map.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> myMap;
myMap.insert({4, {3}});
myMap[4].push_back(2);
myMap[4].push_back(4);
```

Wity myMap[key] you have access to the vector, and you just need to add elements using `push_back`